# Outlook custom forms - Edit message on send event

Tags: vba, outlook

I've modified an outlook message form to include a custom dropdownlist.  I need to append the selected value from the dropdownlist onto the beginning and end of the message text when the user sends.  How do I do this?

Example: User selects "Priority 1" from ddl and sends message "Here is a message."  I would want the recipient to see "Priority 1 Here is a message. Priority 1"  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the message throught the send function of the form you used or are you sending the form throught code i would recomend sending the form throught code this is because you have greater control over the features of the message being sent.

Combining this with the outlook and system variables you can return a fair amount of relevant and usful data.

```
Set DropBox = objPage.Controls("DropBoxName")

With oOMail
.To = "mail@adressee.com.au"
.Subject =  DropBox.Text && "Subject"
.Body =  "message" && DropBox.Text && vbCrLf 
.Send
End With
```